# bootstrap- table cannot align to the right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to align my table to the right of my invoice page like this:

[image]

I place these two tables in the same row and into two columns but however, it's not working as intended. I want the 2nd table to be on the highlighted blue section of the page.

Below is my code:

```
 <div class="row">

      <div class="col-4 col-md-4 col-sm-5 " >
        <table class="table table-bordered ">
        <th><strong> Payment Received </strong></th>
        <tbody>
          <tr style="page-break-after: always;">
            <td class="left">
              Payment Method: xxxxxx
            </td>       
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="left">
              Reference No: 2192012
            </td>       
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="left">
              Amount Paid: RM10,000.00 
            </td>       
          </tr>
          <tbody>
     </table>
 <div>

    <div class="col-4 col-md-4 col-sm-5 mr-auto ">
        <table class="table table-clear">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td class="left">
        <strong>Subtotal</strong>
        </td>
        <td class="right">8.497,00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="left">
        <strong>Transportation(Klang Valley)</strong>
        </td>
        <td class="right">1,699,40</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="left">
         <strong>Transportation(Outstation)</strong>
        </td>
        <td class="right">679,76</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="left">
        <strong> Grand Total</strong>
        </td>
        <td class="right">
        <strong>7.477,36</strong>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="left">
          <strong> Discount</strong>
          </td>
          <td class="right">
          20%
          </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="left">
            <strong> Amount Paid</strong>
            </td>
            <td class="right">
            7.477,36
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="left">
              <strong> Balance Due</strong>
              </td>
              <td class="right">
              <strong>7.477,36</strong>
              </td>
              </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>

        </div>
      </div>
```

I am not sure why it would not align to the right since they share the same row.
What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Issues**

1. `<div>` not closed properly
2. Use `ml-auto` instead of `mr-auto`

**Working Demo**

https://www.codeply.com/p/86T67T7NFV